# Same data in two different databases to improve query performance

Tags: database, elasticsearch, neo4j, bigdata

I'm storing social data in Elasticsearch, but it's so difficult to query it without any kind of joins.

So, I'm thinking a possible way:

**All docs in elasticsearch**. Complete docs with all infos.

**All relations in neo4j**. Only queriable data (dates, id's, etc)

Is this a real-world good option? Same data in two different databases to improve query performance.

**-- UPDATE --**

It's all about querying ability. The structure is:

```
post
{
    id
    date
    message
    tags
    ..
}

user
{
    id
    name
    ..
}

tag
{
    id
    label
    ..
}

comments
{
    post_id
    user_id
    message
    ..
}
```

Elasticsearch is good to store this distributed with amazing scalability. But not good to query something like "*get all users and tags of posts each one commented*".

So, Neo4J is good to perform queries like this, then I'm thinking about store all relations on it.

Comment: Depends as always on your concrete use-case. Perhaps you can repost a concrete use-case that you want to solve.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I've improved details. Thanks for helping!

Comment: In general a graph database is great at handling connections. I recommend just trying it out to see if it works for your query use-cases. Which you haven't mentioned. The query you posted, doesn't really have a start point, does it?